# How to split items in an array obtained from ftp_rawlist()

Tags: php, arrays, ftp, split

I am trying to focus on my PHP skills again but I seem to be stuck on the use of arrays.

I have an array which contains of 700 items. Each item however looks like this:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 u37148 u37148 714513 Dec 31 23:06 01-01-13-etc.tar.gz --> ITEM 1 in array
-rw-r--r-- 1 u37148 u37148 7402504 Dec 31 23:06 01-01-13-home-bnc.tar.gz --> ITEM 2 in array
etcetera
```

Each item, as you can see above, has the same structure and has **9 separate strings separated by a space** delimiter.

What is the code I would need to extract **only the 9th field of each item**?
i would need a new array consisting of :

```
01-01-13-etc.tar.gz ; 01-01-13-home-bnc.tar.gz ; ... and so on.
```

I also might need to be able to access the other fields per item.

Comment: php [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)?

Comment: **[What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)**

Comment: see other replies , thx :)

Answer (score 0):

If the strings in the input array will always have the same structure you could try the following:

```
$result = array();
foreach($input as $item)
    $result[] = explode(" ", $item)[8];
```

**UPDATE**

Based on the comments to fab's answer you could try `preg_split` instead of `explode`:

```
$result = array();
foreach($input as $item)
    $result[] = preg_split("/\s+/", $item, 9)[8];
```

This will split the string by series of whitespaces and return array consisting of exactly 9 items (the last one can contain whitespaces).

Comment: Why are you accessing 16 elements in array, if the string consists of 9 strings joined with spaces?

Comment: OK, it's because of the output formatting which was stated by fab in update to his answer. Check out my new suggestion.

Comment: If you just want the last element (the file name) wrap your preg_split() in an end() function.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the strings at spaces with `$parts = explode(' ', $item)` and then access the ninth part with `$parts[8]` but I'd prefer a regular expression, i.e.:

```
/^(?:.*? ){8}(.*?) /
```

This could make the whole procedure easier if you go one step back. I guess your array is the result of `file($someLogFile)`. In this case, you could read the file into a string instead and fetch your filenames all at once:

```
$log = file_get_contents($someLogFile);
preg_match_all('/^(?:.*? ){8}(.*?) /m', $log, $matches);
$fileNames = $matches[1];
```

### UPDATE

With context from the comments, it's now a lot easier to construct a sensible solution. Unfortunately the output of FTP LIST usually is not a simply parsable tab separated structure but an ASCII table designed for human readability, not machine readability.

Nontheless, if you know the format, a regex that captures all parts is possible.

**Example:**

```
<?php
$ftp = ftp_connect('ftp.mozilla.org');
ftp_login($ftp, 'anonymous', '');
$rawlist = ftp_rawlist($ftp, '/');
$rawlist = join("\n", $rawlist);

preg_match_all('/^([drwx+-]{10})\s+(\d+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\d+)\s+(.{12}) (.*)$/m', $rawlist, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

var_dump($matches);
```

**Output:**

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(8) {
    [0]=>
    string(62) "-rw-r--r--    1 ftp      ftp           528 Nov 01  2007 README"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "-rw-r--r--"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [3]=>
    string(3) "ftp"
    [4]=>
    string(3) "ftp"
    [5]=>
    string(3) "528"
    [6]=>
    string(12) "Nov 01  2007"
    [7]=>
    string(6) "README"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(8) {
    [0]=>
    string(66) "-rw-r--r--    1 ftp      ftp           561 Oct 03 15:44 index.ht
ml"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "-rw-r--r--"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [3]=>
    string(3) "ftp"
    [4]=>
    string(3) "ftp"
    [5]=>
    string(3) "561"
    [6]=>
    string(12) "Oct 03 15:44"
    [7]=>
    string(10) "index.html"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(8) {
    [0]=>
    string(59) "drwxr-xr-x   43 ftp      ftp          4096 Aug 08  2012 pub"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "drwxr-xr-x"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "43"
    [3]=>
    string(3) "ftp"
    [4]=>
    string(3) "ftp"
    [5]=>
    string(4) "4096"
    [6]=>
    string(12) "Aug 08  2012"
    [7]=>
    string(3) "pub"
  }
}
```

The pattern should work for you too as far as I can judge by your example.

Comment: hmm, i think using regular expression is too hard for what i need to do. Second of all, my array is not build from a file ... :)

Comment: the solution still works if you `join` your array first. However, it would be interesting what the source of this array is to find a better way to deal with it.

Comment: the source of my array is a list of files on a remote server.
each file is represented in the array as an item but the problem is that each item is just a line with 9 values i need seperated by a space ...

Comment: i dont think it really matters, but i get the list by making an FTP connection and putting the list inside an array

Comment: it matters because if you use [`ftp_rawlist`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-rawlist.php) you could instead use [`ftp_nlist`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nlist.php) and if you manually use the `LIST` command, you could use `NLST` instead. Problem solved.

Comment: i currently use ftp_rawlist but i dont get what the difference is with ftp_nlist , just the same thing no ?

Comment: it gives you just the file names. I linked the manual for each function, you should read it.

Comment: i already read those , but i used ftp_rawlist because i do need the other fields as well ... so this still does not quiet resolve my question does it ? :)

Comment: Meh, ill leave it as it is right now, it works like a charm, thats all i wanted, thanks fab :)

Comment: thanks for the full opt solution :P i still have one important question though : if i would use the regex as you suggest and create arrays like in your solution,  how would i echo the output by using each seperate field ? like eh : echo $item[0] . " " . $item[1] etc ? Thanks again though ! :D

Comment: well, how do you access arrays? `foreach($matches as $item) { echo $item[6] . " " . $item[7]; }`